# iis7 - regex for redirection

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to redirect http://www.mydomain.com/folder/folder2/
to http://www.mydomain.com/folder/folder3/

What regex do I need in order to do this with the url rewrite kit 2.0 for IIS 7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using direct mapping instead of regex.